# React button not show results after first click, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that would show all the books in the database. However when i click the button the first time it will not list out the books but if i click the button again it will list out all the books, how do i make it list out all the books by only clicking once?

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {getBook} from "../actions/bookActions";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {Container} from "@material-ui/core";
import {Table} from "react-bootstrap";
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";

const bookList = []

class BookListing extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state= {
            id: "",
        };

        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    }

    async onSubmit(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = await this.props.getBook();

        try {
            console.log(data);
            bookList.splice(0, bookList.length)
            data.forEach(book => {
                console.log(book)
                bookList.push(book)
            })
        }catch (exception){
            console.log("no books")
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { errors } = this.state;
        return (
            <Container>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <Button variant="dark" type="submit">Show</Button>{' '}
                    <p>Double click the button</p>
                </form>

                <h2 color={"green"}>{"\n"}Books found {"\n"}</h2>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Book Id</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {bookList.map((book => <tr>
                        <td>{book.id}</td>
                        <td>{book.title}</td>
                        <td>{book.author}</td>
                        <td>{book.category}</td>
                    </tr>))}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </Container>


        )
    }
}

BookListing.propTypes = {
    createProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null, {getBook})(BookListing);
```

Page after pressing the button once:[image]
No books are showing but the console indicates that it is there.

Page after pressing the button second time: [image]
This time the books are listed.

Comment: Have you tried defining bookList as a state?

Comment: Define bookList in the state and use setState to set values. setState will rerender you component.

Comment: In `onSubmit` do you need to add new book to the bookList or replace bookList completely ?

Comment: @NiceBooks i need to replace bookList completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to react to changes to `bookList`, it needs to be part of the state.

```
this.state = {id:'', bookList: [] }
```

In `onSubmit` replace the `bookList` with the books from `data`.

```
// slice without arguments clones an array
this.setState({bookList: data.slice()});
```

When updating state arrays in React, you should use `concat`, `slice`, `filter`, `map` and `concat` rather than `push`, `splice`, `[]` etc. The former return a new array. The latter modify the existing state array, which may be ignored by react. See [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove) for more details.
*The slice in above code, may not really necessary. (Just for demo.)*

Finally, while rendering the list of `<tr>`s you need to specify an unique key for each `<tr>`. You can use `book.id` as the key.

```
<tr key={book.id}>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the button click React component doesn't know that something has changed, because firstly you change the state with setState and then process bookList. So when bookList is changed component doesn't re-rendered, so only on the next click component will get update bookList from previous click.

Of course you can use forceUpdate after updating bookList update, but this is terrible solution.
As @NiceBooks said, put bookList into the state or you can split into two components: one will be responsible for getting bookList and then just pass it to dummy component that knows only how to render bookList. Like
 // here is the logic to get books
 // here show books, handle click

And maybe instead use smth like:
const updatedBookList = [...bookList, ...data]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Booklist is a normal javascript variable in your component. so when you update that variable. react will not identify it because it is not rerendering. so to re-render your component you need to change the value in the state using setState(). currently when you click the button second time it will change the state value initially  "this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});" because of this code. (I found that this set state is not using anywhere in the code also e.target.name could be undefined)

try this code.

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {getBook} from "../actions/bookActions";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {Container} from "@material-ui/core";
import {Table} from "react-bootstrap";
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";



class BookListing extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state= {
            id: "",
            bookList:[]
        };

        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    }

    async onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = await this.props.getBook();
        this.setState({bookList:data})
    }

    render() {
        const { errors, bookList } = this.state;
        return (
            <Container>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit)}>
                    <Button variant="dark" type="submit">Show</Button>{' '}
                    <p>Double click the button</p>
                </form>

                <h2 color={"green"}>{"\n"}Books found {"\n"}</h2>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Book Id</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {bookList && bookList.length && bookList.map((book => <tr>
                        <td>{book.id}</td>
                        <td>{book.title}</td>
                        <td>{book.author}</td>
                        <td>{book.category}</td>
                    </tr>))}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </Container>


        )
    }
}

BookListing.propTypes = {
    createProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null, {getBook})(BookListing);
```